# Getting the "Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' "

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, webpack

I am facing the

> ERROR in ./index.js 1:0
> Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)
> File was processed with these loaders:
> * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these
> loaders.
> > import { startServer } from "./server";
> | import _ from 'lodash';

While executing the `npx webpack` for creating build for NodeJS application. This is my `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` file.

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets:  [
              ['@babel/preset-env']
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "restapi-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "pgtools": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.77.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

`server.ts`

```
import express from 'express';
import Route from './src/routes'

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Parse JSON data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//app.use(express.json());


 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hi World");
});



app.use("/api/v1/order", Route);



// Start the server

export function startServer()
{
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
  });
}
```

`index.js`

```js
import { startServer } from "./server";
//const { startServer } = require("./server");
import _ from 'lodash';

startServer();
```

I have downloaded all the webpack dependencies and have the babel loader dependencies also. Please share your suggestion how this error can be fix.

Comment: did you ever fix this? i'm having the same thing with trying to use React + Webpack + Typescript + Cesium

Answer (score 3):

If you have `"type": "commonjs",` in your package.json, remove it
helped me with same error

Answer (score 2):

In `.eslintrc`, specify the type:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, in my code .eslintrc file is not available. I am using webpack. So can you suggest something on this.